# How to handle more than one eventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two divs like this :

```
  <div id="sun"  > </div>  <div  id="thu" > </div>
```

I want once one of them clicked the `eventListener`:

```
document.getElementById(currentId).addEventListener("click",function(e){});
```

fires the selected one knowing the id of the div.

Comment: There is no jQuery there. Are you looking for a jQuery solution? Otherwise purpose of jQuery tag?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  Can't you simply add the event listener to each `div`?

Comment: @David Because I have a common function between them and it needs just the **ID** of the selected **div**.

Comment: @WissemAchour http://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm This is just an example, you can find many many more on the web

Comment: Add the event listener to both the divs by finding element by id and adding event listener to it individually, then define a function which will be your handler and pass it as 2nd argument to both the divs.

Answer (score 1):

You need this :

```
function eventHandler(e) {
   //what needs to be done after user clicks the divs will come here
}

document.getElementById('sun').addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false);
document.getElementById('thu').addEventListener("click", eventHandler, false);
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but not too DRY. How about `function handle(id) { document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", eventHandler); }`, then `handle('sun'); handle('thu');`?

Comment: Yes, very much correct and helpful if someone has a large set of elements to add event listener to, just need to pass the id.

Comment: How about `function handle(id, handler) { document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("click", handler); }, then handle('sun', eventHandler); handle('thu', eventHandler);`? will be helpful if there are different handlers.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple. Basically the context of the event callback function is the actual html Element that is clicked. So the "this" selector is the actual source of the event.

```
document.getElementById(currentId).addEventListener("click",function(e){
        var id=this.getAttribute('id');
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the OP's question, which is how to attach the event listener to **both** divs (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the elements and add an onclick event to them. Or just add the listener individually.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#sun, #thu").forEach(el =>
    el.onclick = () => {
        console.log(el.id) 
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for one common event hander for both div.

If yes, then you can achieve this by giving common class to both div and then register event hander by class selector like below:

HTML code:

```
<div id="sun" class="myClass"> </div> 
<div id="thu" class="myClass" > </div>
```

java script code:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
 for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
        classname[i].addEventListener('click', event_handler_name, false);
    }
```

or

```
$('.myClass').click(event_handler_name);
```

jQuery does the looping part for you, where as you need to do in plain javascript.

Comment: There is no API `getElementByClass`. There is `getElementsByClassName`, but it returns an array which you cannot call `addEventListener` on directly. Did you bother to test this code before posting it as an "answer"?